# How do I create a full-bleed background image on text mouseover?

Tags: plugins, images, media, gallery

I have a portfolio of images I'd like to display on my home page in full bleed that corresponds to specific text that is hovered-over with the mouse. Like [this](http://mssngpeces.com/) site, but without the video aspect. I've looked at various Wordpress hover plugins, but they're all for small-scale grid images. Does anyone know of any better plugins or ways to modify these grid plugins to do what I want?

Comment: If you'd like to customize a plugin, contact the developers of the plugin. Plugin recommendations are off-topic here on WPSE. If you'd like to create this implementation yourself, you can post the code that you've come up with so far and get assistance from there.